# MongoDB use reduce "$$this" variable as an object key

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, reduce

**Current code:**

```
let someObject = {a: "hello ", b: "world", c: "!"};
...
// QUERY
$reduce: {
   input: ["a", "b", "c"],
   initialValue: "",
   in: { $concat : ["$$value", someObject["$$this"]] }
}
```

**Expected output:**

```
hello world!
```

**Current output:**

```
null
```

**Reason:** "$$this" is considered as `"$$this" string`, and **not** as a reduce variable `$$this` when used as a property in square brackets. `someObject["$$this"]` is `undefined`.

**Fix**: ???

I have tried everything, using it inside mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), using it inside a nested $concat with an empty string and a lot of other things I have forgotten by now. I think I am missing something. How can I force it to be `$$this` variable instead of string `"$$this"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB aggregation framework has [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt), but no `$objectElemAt` where you can pass `expression` to get object value.

**Walkaround:** We need to convert object to array, filter that `key:value` and return the value.

```
{a:"hello", b:"world", c:"!"} 
to 
[ {k:"a", v:"hello"}, {k:"b", v:"world"}, {k:"c", v:"!"} ]
```

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: ["a","b","c"],
              as: "abc",
              in: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    someObject: {
                      $filter: {
                        input: {
                          $objectToArray: {a: "hello ",b: "world",c: "!"}
                        },
                        cond: {
                          $eq: ["$$this.k","$$abc"]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  in: {
                    $ifNull: [
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$$someObject.v", 0]
                      },
                      ""
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $concat: ["$$value","$$this"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lncdrJfoCSP)

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I will play around with this